# Fix serialized HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, serialization, escaping

I have something that's gone through serialization, so in Java, each of the quotes are replaced by

```
&quot;
```

Is there a generic, robust solution to fixing this kind of string and turning into a normal java string without those "escape" characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons' StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String hello = "&quot;hello&quot;";
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(hello));

}
```

Which yields

`"hello"`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you Unbescape [ http://www.unbescape.org ] (of which I'm the author) as a general escape / unescape library for Java. It supports HTML 4, HTML5, JavaScript, CSS, etc.

Important differences with StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons-Lang is that Unbescape supports unescaping the whole set of HTML5 entities, which are more than 2,000 ('entity' = `&whatever;`), the whole Unicode character set (up to U+10FFFF instead of just U+FFFF) and that it is much faster, up to 50x depending on the scenario, so it is better suited for iterative or intensive unescape operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
NewString = BrokenString.replace("&quot", "\"");
```

Comment: It'd be replaceAll. But anyway, that's no good. I want to make sure that I've gotten every replacement of this type.

Comment: Is the html saved in a string before serialization?

Comment: If so, you could brake the string up into a string array, where each string is starts/ends where one of these changes occur, then after deserialization just re build the string and insert the relevant characters!